# Mongo shuts down instantly

Tags: mongodb

Tried looking this up, but can only find similar issues but not the same. When I try to launch mongodb from the terminal using the 'mongod' command, I get the following:

```
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=861 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Dylans-MacBook-Pro-2.local
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-02-27T15:48:17.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-02-27T15:48:17.875+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2017-02-27T15:48:17.875+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-02-27T15:48:17.875+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-02-27T15:48:17.875+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-02-27T15:48:17.875+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Any ideas? Thanks! (Using Mac OS 10.12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db

Basically you need to make sure the /data/db directory is writeable. You probably created it manually without write access.